# Fix div to make bar above image with CSS

Tags: css

This [piece of code](https://jsfiddle.net/aqYbt/) works fine on firefox. However with everything else it doesnt work as desired. I am trying to make the X on the top right with the image beneath the title/X as it shows in the firefox image below

[image]

HTML:

```html
<div class="CenterImg">

<div class="temp"><div class="fn">namedkfjdjfdjfsjdfijsdifjdsfdfsddsdf.jpg</div><div class="remove">X</div><div class="imgdiv"><img src="http://th960.photobucket.com/albums/ae89/DarkKitteh/Stuffz/th_Avatars_Funny_Cat_With_Headphones.gif"/></div></div>

    <div class="temp"><div class="fn">name.jpg</div><div class="remove">X</div><div class="imgdiv"><img src="http://th960.photobucket.com/albums/ae89/DarkKitteh/Stuffz/th_Avatars_Funny_Cat_With_Headphones.gif"/></div></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.CenterImg > div
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    float: left;
}
.CenterImg  div .imgdiv img
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
}
.CenterImg  div .imgdiv
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width:  150px;
    height: 150px;
}


.CenterImg > div > .fn
{
    max-width: 138px;
    width: 138px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: inherit;
    float: left;
}
.remove
{
    float: right;
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? How is it actually rendered elsewhere? I don't have access to all browsers right now so I can't see for myself.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: title is to the left and the x is to the right of the image. Instead of the image being beneath them both. Which causes a huge white space to the left of the image under the text. I tried writing float: right and clear: both to no avail (i havent tried them together tho). I assume everyone has IE installed, even 6 (which i dont as i am on win7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure the image is underneath the text and the "X". In order to do this, you need to add a div that clears the space as follows:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Place this div under your text and the "X", and above the image div. This will guarantee the image always sits below your text without overlap.

In the context of your first box, this code would be:

```
<div class="temp"><div class="fn">namedkfjdjfdjfsjdfijsdifjdsfdfsddsdf.jpg</div>
<div class="remove">X</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="imgdiv"><img src="http://th960.photobucket.com/albums/ae89/DarkKitteh/Stuffz/th_Avatars_Funny_Cat_With_Headphones.gif"/></div></div>
```

Comment: It works :). Thanks. Also i see theres many rev before that was it you? http://jsfiddle.net/aqYbt/10/

Comment: Hiya, yeah - I haven't used jsfiddle before so I didn't know it would show you my tinkering :). Glad it worked!

Comment: Its very handy. If you hit run it hides the revisions and you can hit update to have a more permanent version (which i like so i can test on other browsers or not worry if my browser crash/close)